# ¿Cómo recibir y retornar variables en Laravel?

Tags: php

Busque información acerca de este tema y no tuve éxito.
La idea es crear un metodo para realizar una tarea, pero no se como llamar a ese método de la misma o distinta clase.
Ejemplo:

```
 public function resuelve($x, $y)
    {
       $suma= $x +$y;

       return $suma;
   }
```

Y digamos que tengo otro método y quiero mandar los valores al método resuelve, pero lastimosamente no funciona.

```
public function ejemplo()
{
    $valor1 = 11;
    $suma = resuelve($valor1, 22);
}
```

Comment: A quienes agregan de nuevo las etiquetas de Laravel, les aseguro que esto es PHP básico y aplica a cualquier aplicación hecha en algún framework, las respuestas son TODAS basadas en sintaxis regular PHP. Sobran las etiquetas de Laravel en este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que laravel para trabajar entre distintas clases funciona con namespaces y para llamar a una clase tienes que llamarla previamente y definirla al principio en el fichero que quieres , que ya te pone el la direccion "namespace.....".

```
use namespace/to/directory/class_php as clase;
...
$class = new clase();
$a = $class->funcion(x,y);
```

o

```
$class = new  namespace/to/directory/class_php();
$a = $class->funcion(x,y);
```

Comment: Muy bueno. me sirvió, lo estoy usando de este manera 

`use  App\Http\Controllers\ExamplesController;`

Comment: Esto te ayudará con esas cosas , son los estandares de php ,http://www.php-fig.org/ , todo lo que haga f.alta ya sabes . Para algo se está

Comment: php artisan make:controller <nombre> , ya te lo crea todo automáticamente en laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Si estan en la misma clase no olvides poner la referencia a $this

```
public function ejemplo()
{
    $valor1 = 11;
    $suma = $this->resuelve($valor1, 22);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me olvide del famoso $this. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $suma = $this->resuelve($valor1, 22);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Atención: para llamar los métodos de una clase no siempre se usa
>   $this. Lo explicaré en el punto (C).

**A. Primero la clase, por supuesto**

Para usar una clase en PHP primero debe **crearse una instancia de la misma**, empleando la palabra reservada `new`.

```
$instancia = new ClaseSencilla();
```

Esto también se puede hacer con una variable:

```
$nombreClase = 'ClaseSencilla';
$instancia = new $nombreClase(); // new ClaseSencilla()
```

Se supone que antes se ha hecho el `include` o `require` del archivo PHP que contiene la clase. Aunque las mismas se pueden invocar también usando un [`autoloader`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.autoload.php).

**B. El uso de `$this`**

Una vez creada la instancia, podemos llamar cualquier función (o método) de la misma usando la pseudovariable **`$this`**.

Pero, para usarla, conviene que veamos algo de lo que dice la [ayuda de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php):

> La pseudovariable **$this está disponible cuando un método es invocado**
>   **dentro del contexto de un objeto**. $this es una referencia al objeto
>   invocador (usualmente el objeto al cual el método pertenece, aunque
>   puede que sea otro objeto si el método es llamado estáticamente desde
>   el contexto de un objeto secundario). A partir de PHP 7.0.0, la
>   llamada estática a un método no estático desde un contexto
>   incompatible resulta en que $this no esté definido dentro del método.
>   Una llamada estática a un método no estático desde un contexto no
>   compatible está obsoleta desde PHP 5.6.0. A partir de PHP 7.0.0, una
>   llamada estática a un método no estático está obsoleta en general
>   (incluso si se llama desde un contexto compatible). Antes de PHP
>   5.6.0, tales llamadas ya ocasionaban un aviso de estrictez.

***Algunos ejemplos de la pseudovariable `$this`***

Se asume que para este ejemplo error_reporting está inhabilitado; de lo contrario, el siguiente código emitirá avisos de estrictez y obsolescencia, respectivamente, dependiendo de la versión de PHP.

> ```
> <?php
> class A
> {
>     function foo()
>     {
>         if (isset($this)) {
>             echo '$this está definida (';
>             echo get_class($this);
>             echo ")\n";
>         } else {
>             echo "\$this no está definida.\n";
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> class B
> {
>     function bar()
>     {
>         A::foo();
>     }
> }
>
> $a = new A();
> $a->foo();
>
> A::foo();
> $b = new B();
> $b->bar();
>
> B::bar();
> ?>
> ```
>
> Salida del ejemplo anterior en PHP 5:
>
> ```
> $this está definida (A)
> $this no está definida.
> $this está definida (B)
> $this no está definida.
> ```
>
> Salida del ejemplo anterior en PHP 7:
>
> ```
> $this está definida (A)
> $this no está definida.
> $this no está definida.
> $this no está definida.
> ```

**C. El caso especial de los métodos estáticos**

**No siempre se usa `$this`** para llamar los métodos de una clase.

¿Y eso? Pues porque una clase puede tener **[métodos estáticos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php)**. 
Consideremos esta clase:

```
class Foo {
    public static function unMetodoEstatico() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Según PHP:

> Debido a que los métodos estáticos se pueden invocar sin tener creada
>   una instancia del objeto, **la seudovariable `$this` no está disponible
>   dentro de los métodos declarados como estáticos**.

¿Y entonces, qué usamos? Pues los métodos estáticos se invocan usando **`::`** entre el nombre de la clase y el método.

Ejemplo de llamada del método de la clase anterior:

```
Foo::unMetodoEstatico();
$nombre_clase = 'Foo';
$nombre_clase::unMetodoEstatico(); // A partir de PHP 5.3.0
```

Tampoco se usa el operador **`->`** para llamar las propiedades de un método estático. La explicación está en el enlace de más arriba, lo pongo aquí para que lo sepamos simplemente.
:)

Comment: Intenté hacerlo con Laravel y no me funcionó

Comment: Debiste decir desde el principio que se trataba de Laravel. Allí las cosas funcionan de otro modo, como ya ha sido explicado. Ahora has editado la pregunta, bien, pero el esfuerzo que he hecho para responderte es vano. De todos modos me alegra que hayas encontrado la solución. Saludos.

Comment: Alguien editó mi pregunta y borró la etiqueta Laravel, pero muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: @Aunque no esté en la etiqueta, si se indica en el título de la pregunta cómo está ahora quienes leemos y tratamos de responder ya sabemos que se trata de un framework en específico. Sirve de experiencia para una próxima. Saludos :)

Comment: @A.Cedano buenas yo no uso php ect y practicamente mis conocimientos en estas tecnologias es nulo, pero revisando preguntas acabe aqui, y veo o creo que su respuesta no es valida para esta pregunta, segun comentarios, si es asi, es una pena, a mi no me importa crear una pregunta, para que usted responda con esta respuesta y no si pierda, y  asi eliminarla de esta pregunta, si no es el sitio mas adecuado (que no lo se).Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Pues la verdad que tomé mi tiempo en preparar la respuesta porque la persona no había indicado que se trataba de Laravel :( Lo dijo luego. Cuando escribo preguntas tengo como norma poner 1º el lenguaje y luego la pregunta, por ejemplo `PHP-Laravel: ... y a continuación la pregunta` así sin problemas de etiquetas se sabe de que va la pregunta. De todos modos la dejé por si podía servir a alguien. Creo que sí, que sería bueno que exista como respuesta a otra pregunta. Tengo la duda si podría existir como respuesta aquí y en otra eventual pregunta. Lo consultaré en el meta. Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano yo estube mirando las ediciones y se monto un lio, por eso y por los comentarios, que lei, le comente lo anterior, poder estar en dos lados, si, pero, la idea era que la borrara de aqui pues el usuario comento que no le funcionaba para laravel, y si eso es cierto su respuesta no responde a la pregunta y podria causar -1 en su respuesta. ya me dira algo.Saludos